# Does typescript allow me to add a function declaration type instead of using a function expression?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Say I have the form

```
const mypluginCallback: FastifyPluginAsync<MyPluginOptions> = async (
  fastify,
  options,
) => {
  
};
```

And FastifyPluginAsync is a function type with the following form:

```
export type FastifyPluginAsync<Options extends FastifyPluginOptions = Record<never, never>, Server extends RawServerBase = RawServerDefault> = (
  instance: FastifyInstance<Server, RawRequestDefaultExpression<Server>, RawReplyDefaultExpression<Server>>,
  opts: Options
) => Promise<void>;
```

Is it possible to something similar but with a function declaration instead of a function expression?

```
function myPluginCallback() {}
```

If I wanted to reap the benefit of hoisting function declarations, how can I achieve this?

Comment: You'll probably need to retype definition of `FastifyPluginAsync` https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/main/types/plugin.d.ts#L22, something like https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsIwLZgA4A2CA5qhADwDyeamIMApgB7IMQAm9AYqGnGAAUipCNVoR6AXhgAlBlHQAnduQgMAbg0UAaGGs2KAfLoDKWg4xZtOs4AHczigwCFQDGNJn3HBgCIM4YAQCZEMACgBYACgYGDIQZGBoBgAuGB4E1H4ASQlE5PIfLV0vOzkARwQGBP9A4OQAUSY8RWqQDAoioxL7OUIwWqCQppa2jsLzLUNjaNj0GhA0sQ6QaIBKNIFFdGxUEAZydXRUdkMYAG8YADobmABfIA or use `Parameters` and `ReturnType` utils

Answer (score 0):

> If I wanted to reap the benefit of hoisting function declarations, how can I achieve this?

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by this, but if what you're trying to do is set the return type of `myPluginCallback` using the `function` keyword to `FastifyPluginAsync<MyPluginOptions>` you can simply do the following:

```js
function myPluginCallback(): FastifyPluginAsync<MyPluginOptions> {}
```

And if you need a promise, as you're using the `async` keyword in the arrow function, you can do this:

```js
async function myPluginCallback(): Promise<FastifyPluginAsync<MyPluginOptions>> {}
```

#### Updated answer for updated question:

I believe this is what you're trying to do:

```js
async function myPluginCallback<
  Options extends FastifyPluginOptions = Record<never, never>,
  Server extends RawServerBase = RawServerDefault
>(
  instance: FastifyInstance<
    Server,
    RawRequestDefaultExpression<Server>,
    RawReplyDefaultExpression<Server>
  >,
  options: Options,
): Promise<void> {
  //
}
```

And this is how you would use it:

```js
await myPluginCallback<MyPluginCallbackOptions, MyPluginCallbackServer>(instance, options) {
  // 
}
```

Comment: I've updated my OP. FastifyPluginAsync is a function type, not a return type.